# Should I use more than one panel in a java game ?

Tags: java, game-design

I' m creating a game in java, and it has this schema:

I use the `main class` to launch my game and I create a frame to add a panel, that is defined into `GamePanel` class.

```
public class MainFrame {

    private static final MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
    private final JFrame frame;

    private MainFrame() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.add(new GamePanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static final MainFrame getMainFrameInstance() {
    return mainFrame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MainFrame.getMainFrameInstance();
        }
    });
    }
```

and the `game panel` class

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseListener,   MouseMotionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // thread and game loop
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
    private int FPS = 60;
    private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;
    private long start;
    private long elapsed;
    private long wait;

    // mouse events
    private long mousePressed;
    private long mouseReleased;
    private long mousePressTime;

    // mouse pressed force
    public static int seconds = 0;
    // image
    public static BufferedImage image;
    private boolean firstCall = true;

    // game manager
    private GameManager gameManager;
    // renderManager
    private RenderManager renderManager;

    public GamePanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GuiDimension.WIDTH.getValue(), GuiDimension.HEIGHT.getValue()));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    if (thread == null) {
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    }

    // prevent to be done all method.
    private synchronized void init() {
    image = new BufferedImage(GuiDimension.WIDTH.getValue(), GuiDimension.HEIGHT.getValue(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    gameManager = new GameManager(States.LOADING.getValue());
    gameManager.loadCurrentState(States.LOADING.getValue());
    renderManager = new RenderManager(gameManager);
    MainFrame.getMainFrameInstance().setCursor(CursorStatus.CUSTOMCURSOR.getValue());
    running = true;

    }

    public void run() {
    init();
    // game loop
    while (running) {
        start = System.nanoTime();
        gameManager.update();
        KeyInput.getKeyInputInstance().update();
        MouseInput.getMouseInputInstance().update();
        // refresh panel components
        repaint();
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        wait = (targetTime - elapsed / 1000000) - 8;
        if (wait <= 0)
        wait = 6;
        try {
        Thread.sleep(wait);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphic) {
    super.paintComponent(graphic);
    Graphics2D graphic2D = image.createGraphics();
    // to best visualization of the shapes and all graphics components
    graphic2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphic2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    if (firstCall) {
        // for the first call of paintComponent()
        // i draw this after other thing
        graphic.drawImage(ImageLoader.LOADING, 0, 0, this);
        firstCall = false;
        // other graphic calls
    } else {
        renderManager.setRenderState(graphic2D);
        graphic.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
    // clear graphics resources after use them
    graphic2D.dispose();
    image.flush();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    KeyInput.getKeyInputInstance().keySet(keyEvent.getKeyCode(), true);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    KeyInput.getKeyInputInstance().keySet(keyEvent.getKeyCode(), false);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    MouseInput.getMouseInputInstance().setAction(MouseInput.getMouseInputInstance().getPRESSED());
    mousePressed = mouseEvent.getWhen();

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    MouseInput.getMouseInputInstance().setAction(MouseInput.getMouseInputInstance().getRELEASED());
    mouseReleased = mouseEvent.getWhen();
    mousePressTime = mouseReleased - mousePressed;
    seconds = (int) ((mousePressTime / 1000) % 60);
    if (seconds <= 0) {
        seconds = 1;
    }
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    MouseInput.getMouseInputInstance().setPosition(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
    ;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    MouseInput.getMouseInputInstance().setAction(MouseInput.getMouseInputInstance().getPRESSED());
    MouseInput.getMouseInputInstance().setPosition(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    }

}
```

Now, my game works pretty well but **is it correct to maintain only one panel for the game ?** I find this way easier and more convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single panel is the right way to go when using Java Swing to create a Java game. By using a panel, you basically ask Java: "Give me an area in the interface to draw my game on." You can then draw everything you need onto that panel.

I don't see any immediate use for having multiple panels. Even if you were to create a split-screen multiplayer game, you'll typically reserve multiple portions of a single panel to draw your different views. You don't want to adapt the structure of your game to the structure of the Java Swing framework.

An exception to this rule could be if you were to create an event-based game. For instance, if you were to create a minesweeper game, it would make sense to use a panel to render the field, several labels to render the score ... etc. As, the Minesweeper game world only advanced upon player input. It is thus event-based and could fit into the Java Swing framework.

But, as you are using a gameloop to update your game at a steady 60 frames per second pace, you'll want just a single panel and take care of all drawing yourself.

Comment: Excuse me, can you define well what's mean event-based game?

Comment: Yeah, sure. When you're creating a game, you'll want to update your  game world every once in a while (eg. to make enemies move). There are various ways to handle this.

In your game, the world is updated at a fixed rate, 60 times per second. 

A different option is to only update the game when something happened. Some games (eg. Minesweeper) don't change unless some event happens. In this case, it doesn't make sense to update 60 times a second. Rather, you wait for an event to happen, and update the game world after the event occurred. This is how Java Swing operates, as it is meant for GUI's